# What Happened To King David's Parents?

Tags: midrash, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, murder

I read somewhere (I believe it was a midrash) that King David's parents were murdered?

Is this this factual or is it an allegory for some other interpretation, e.g losing their money/status?

Comment: What do you mean "just a Midrash **or** factual"

Comment: See Shmuel 1:22:1-4

Comment: Fun fact : his parents names were Yishai and Nitzeves

Answer (score 2):

You read *Midrash Tanchuma* (Buber edition) Vayikra 28,1 which says the King of Moav killed Dovid's parents and brothers except Elihu his brother.

> ויסע משם אברהם. כתיב רעך ורע אביך וגו' (משלי כז י), זה חנון בן נחש מלך בני עמון, שנאמר ויהי אחרי כן וימת (נחש) מלך בני עמון וגו' (ש"ב י א), ויאמר דוד אעשה חסד עם חנון בן נחש וגו' (שם שם ב), אמר ר' ברכיה בשם ר' אלעזר בן פדת ומה חסד עשה נחש עם דוד שאמר כאשר עש אביו עמדי חסד (שם), אלא **כשברח דוד משאול הלך דוד וכל בית אביו אצל מואב, אמר להם קבלו בית אבא, שנאמר וינחם את פני מלך מואב (ש"א כב ד), ויאמר (ישב) [אל מלך מואב יצא] נא אבי ואמי (שם שם ג), וקבלו אותם, כיון שיצא דוד עמד מלך מואב והרג לאביו ולאמו ולאחיו של דוד, לא נשתייר מהם אלא אחד, שנאמר ליהודה אליהוא מאחי דוד (דה"א כ זיח)**.

Even though there might be an allegorical interpretation to*Midrash*, in general it should still be interpreted literally as the Maharsha says in Bava Basra 74b:
ודע כי יש לנו להאמין בכל הדברים האלו בפשטן ואף שהמפרשים האריכו בדרוש הזה לפי כוונתם יעוין שם אין הדברים יוצאין ממשמען ודו"ק:
 Though as the Maharsha implies, there *are* those *Meforshim* who would explain certain Midrashim uniquely out of literal context in an allegorical meaning.
But this would only apply in places like Bava Basra 74b (where the Maharsha made his statement) in the context of the Leviathan multiplying and destroying the world, where there is difficultly for some Meforshim in understanding literally hence the Machlokes arose whether to interperet literally. But in events quoted in Seder Olam or other Midrashim (such as the one above) stating historical facts of when various people died, the Midrash is there to fill in the gaps of factual information not provided in Tenach.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that is the meaning of the enigmatic phrase by in *L'Dovid Hashem Ori* (Tehillim 27:10) that "my father and mother have foresaken me, but Hashem gathers me in."